# Confused about Catalan number equation

Tags: permutations, combinations, catalan-numbers

Why is the Catalan number $$C_{n+1} = C_0 C_n+C_1C_{n-1}+\cdots+C_{n-1}C_1+C_nC_0,$$ and not
$$C_{n+1} = C_0C_{n+1} + C_1C_n +\cdots+ C_nC_1 + C_{n+1}C_0 ?$$
In the latter formula, $0+(n+1) = 1+n = (n+1)$, but the former formula miss 1. It seems missing 1 is correct and wondering what is the logics behind the scene.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171214102548/http://mathforum.org/mathimages/index.php/Catalan_Numbers)

Comment: If anyone could advise, it will be great. :)

Comment: I do not understand your question. The first relation is true for Catalan numbers, the second is obviously wrong because, since $C_0=1$ and $C_n>0$ for all $n$, the sum on the right-hand side is larger than $2C_{n+1}$ (consider the first and last terms).

Comment: The simple answer is that the above formula is correct, while the bottom formula is not. Also notice that the above formula is defined recursively, i.e. you can find the value of $C_{n+1}$ from the values $C_0, C_1 \dots C_n$. In the latter formula, as written, you have given $C_{n+1}$ in terms of itself, which is a warning that you might want to rerrange it.

Comment: Thanks @improve, what do you mean the bottom formula?

Comment: @Tom-Tom, my question is, for Catalan number n+1, we consider multiply Catalan number 0 with n, 1 with n-1, and to me it seems we are missing one? (0 + n == 1 + n-1 == n, but != n +1)? I am wondering why we are missing one here?

Comment: @LinMa I just meant the formula $C_{n+1} = C_0C_{n+1} + C_1C_n +\cdots+ C_nC_1 + C_{n+1}C_0$

Comment: @Improve, thanks for the clarifications. And my question is, for Catalan number n+1, we consider multiply Catalan number 0 with n, 1 with n-1, and to me it seems we are missing one? (0 + n == 1 + n-1 == n, but != n +1)? I am wondering why we are missing one here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of thinking about the recursion is a sort of divide and conquer.  For example, one combinatorial interpretation of the Catalan numbers is that $C_n$ is the number of ways of drawing $n$ non-intersecting chords between $2n$ points on a circle (Part (n) of Stanley's infamous "[catalan exercise](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/catalan.pdf)").

Here the recurrence for $C_{n+1}$ comes from marking a single point (call it $x$) and considering the chord through that point.

The chord through $x$ divides the circle into two parts, one starting clockwise from $x$ and one counterclockwise.  If there's $k$ chords in one part, there's $n-k$ chords in the other part, so there's $C_k$ ways to draw the chords in the clockwise part, and $C_{n-k}$ ways to draw the chords in the counterclockwise part.  The recursion comes from adding up over all $k$.

A key thing here: Even though there's $n+1$ chords in the original circle, when I do my divide-and-conquer I'm only dividing up $n$ chords.  This is because the chord through $x$ is not included in either half.  That's where the missing "1" went.

A similar thing happens many other times when you prove something is counted by the Catalan numbers using the recursive formula: You fix one small part (one triangle in your triangulation, or the time of the first return to $0$ of your Dyck path).  This divides the rest of your objects into two classes, but the sum of the sizes of the two classes is smaller than the original, because you've already fixed what happens in one place.

Comment: Hi Kevin, excellent reply, you Rock! One more question, how do you guarantee in the recursive representation, `Ck * Cn-k` does not product duplicate items for `Cn-k * Ck`

Comment: The guarantee comes from the two classes we divide things into are distinguished.  In the chords on a circle example, we have the clockwise vs. counterclockwise parts.  For the Dyck paths, we have the part before the first return to $0$, and the part after the first return to $0$.  Which part has which size changes from the $C_k C_{n-k}$ term to the $C_{n-k} C_k$ term.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. It takes me a few hours over the weekend to re-study the theory (http://mathforum.org/mathimages/index.php/Catalan_Numbers) and your reply. I have one more question regarding to use case of "Balanced Parentheses", especially how to avoid repetition counting in "Balanced Parentheses" use case. I think for n=3 ()()(), in the page (http://mathforum.org/mathimages/index.php/Catalan_Numbers), collection A will be (), and collection B will be ()(), correct? Thanks.

Comment: Right.  The divide-and-conquer here is based on where the left-most open parenthesis closes, and in this case it closes immediately.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, mark your reply as answered and appreciate again for the patience to explain to me. :)

Comment: And 50 more points granted. :)